# sample app to illustrate use of OData in NancyFx

Tags: odata, nancy

I am developing a sample app to  illustrate use of OData in my application(NancyFx based).
Can any one help in get started with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not familiar with NanchFx. As far as I know, it is a different framework to build Web application than Web API. 
Second, what do you mean a "sample app" ?  Is that a app to build an OData service or to consume a OData service? If it's for server side, maybe you need to get started with [ODataLib](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/). If it's for consuming, then maybe a little bit more options like [OData client for .NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/), [OData client code generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937), and other JavaScript library supporting OData like JayData, Olingo ODataJS, Breeze, etc. HTH

Comment: sample app i mean an OData service, which can return Json results for uri query like
    http://localhost:31837/Test/customer?$filter=Name eq 'ram'

Comment: Well then, as far as I know, you have to use ODataLib as I mentioned above directly.